# Angularfire2 Update a Record

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, angularfire2

i'm pretty new to angular and I'm in the process of building a small web app.

I've managed to setup angularfire 2 and successfully managed to create a new list entry using Push().

Let's say my list (users) consists user email and first name. only the email is added via the Push method and i want to update that record by adding first name.

I referred to the Angularfire2 documentation and managed to get this far:

```
 usrEmail: string;
 usrData: AngularFireList<any>;
 usr: Observable<any>;


  constructor( private authService: AuthService, private afd: AngularFireDatabase) {


    this.usrData = this.afd.list('/users')
    // now get the current user
    this.usr = this.usrData.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
     });

  }
```

I'm not sure how i should filter the list by the **usrEmail** and obtain the key to update the record.

Any help pointing me at the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you've used gets all `/users` not just the single user with the matching email address.

I've assumed that you have access to the email address and it's assigned to a variable `userEmailAddress`.

```
this.usr = this.afd.list('/users', ref => ref
  .orderByChild('usrEmail')
  .equalTo(userEmailAddress)
)
.snapshotChanges()
.map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
})
.first()
.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    console.log('Snapshot Key: ', snapshot.key);
    console.log('Snapshot Payload: ', snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

The output of the `snapshot.key` will be the key you're trying to fetch.

However in your scenario there would be a better way to store the customers email address. You can create a path containing the user-id within the database, such as;

I'll assume you have access to the uid via the the authService. `this.authService.uid`

```
this.afd.object(`/users/${this.authService.uid}`).update({
  email: userEmailAddress
});
```

The `uid` of the user will never change and it's unique to that user, so you can create database paths with it for easy access.

Comment: thank you very much for for the swift response. thank you very  much, your suggested method is a much better design. one quick clarification, can i use push() to create a new path? Will test the code in a while and mark as answered :)

Comment: Push is used to generate a unique path. If you do something like `this.afd.list(`/users/${this.authService.uid}`).push({ email: userEmailAddress });` it will generate a path like `/users/someUid/someRandomPushKey/email` which is a long path with the `someRandomPushKey` in the middle of the path, making it difficult to decode. Whereas if you use `set` or `update` it will write to the path you specify without adding extra keys. The path would be `/users/someUid/email` which is much shorter.